# Get the main type out of a composite type in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

let's assume I have types defined as:

```
data_type1 = list[str]
data_type2 = set[int]
```

and so on, how can I get just the main type (like list or set) by analyzing the two data types?

I tried:

```
issubclass(data_type1, list)
issubclass(data_type2, set)
```

but it returns False

Any idea?

Comment: Using `__origin__` as people's answers suggest is probably best. Another option is `data_type1.mro()[0]` which would also give you `<class 'list'>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `__origin__` attribute. [This attribute points at the non-parameterized generic class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#genericalias.__origin__).

```
>>> data_type1 = list[str]
>>> data_type1.__origin__
<class 'list'>
>>> data_type2 = set[int]
>>> data_type2.__origin__
<class 'set'>
>>> data_type2.__origin__ == set
True
```

or using [`get_origin` API from `typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin).

```
>>> data_type1 = list[str]
>>> 
>>> from typing import get_origin
>>> get_origin(data_type1)
<class 'list'>
>>> get_origin(data_type1) == list
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `isistance` or `issubclass` don't support this type.
This type is known as a Generic Alias.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias

Instead, you can use the `__origin__` property to get the datatype.

(Extracted from the link above)

**genericalias.**origin****

```
This attribute points at the non-parameterized generic class:

list[int].__origin__
<class 'list'>
```